# When should something be registered as a service?

Tags: linux, services

I've red a few tutorials on how to set P2P clients up, specifically Deluge. For some reason all of them say to register it as a service. Why is this? I've just been starting it manually in the background and this seems like a much smarter idea for control.

One example from https://sbcguides.com/install-deluge-on-raspberry-pi/

> Now, lets stop the services and Deluge components from running so we
> can make some needed changes.
>
> sudo systemctl stop deluged sudo systemctl stop deluge-web

What's the point? In the connection manager of deluge it calls itself a daemon, so is it automatically a daemon?

Comment: If you find it smarter to start Delug manually, then do it. Some people think, it is polite to keep the service up with the startup of the system. The more bitTorrent peers are active, the better it is for all. That's the spirit of the community; IMHO. Perhaps you have to pay for network traffic, or you do not trust bittorrent or a continuously open network connection. Seriously, if you don't want to use it as a service, just let it be.

Comment: To the title question: Something should be registered as a service, if you want to start it with the system boot. -- To the last question: I don't know really but I guess, if you start a transfer, delug is in daemon mode to avoid stopping the download/upload when stopping the GUI. I often use Transmission. Once I started a download the deamon stays as a Destop symbol even if I close the Window. But I doubt that is done with a service. Just by running der Transmission server in background. I did not create an answer, as the question is oppinonated IMHO.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer to [my understanding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192058/what-is-technical-difference-between-daemon-service-and-process) Linux (which Raspbian is) uses the name "daemon" where as Windows calls them "services". Is this correct? Is Debian/Raspbian an exception? In the [linked article](https://sbcguides.com/install-deluge-on-raspberry-pi/) it states "Create a new service to run the Deluge daemon" which I find confusing.

Comment: I don't know whether a unix deamon is like a Windows service because, I don't know how a windows service is defined. A Unix/Linux deamon is a process which runs in the background, ie. its parent process is the init process (with PID 0) and there are no io channels attached to a terminal. You can only interact with Signals (kill command), network , custom io or inter process communicatiion IPC with such a process.

Comment: On linux the term service is used for modules that are initialized on startup. Often they are started in background - as a deamon. But the imported thing is, that services are started automatically when the raspi is booted and you have no choice to not start it. If you don't configured it as a service, you can start is manually if you want.